# How to "match" multiple items using regular expression?

Tags: regex

Here is my text

```
common_result = "Devices:\n\thci1\t00:50:B6:80:4D:5D\n\thci0\t00:15:83:15:A2:CB\n";
```

I like to write regular expression to "match" both hci0 and hci1 parts.

This C++ code matches only the FIRST occurrence of hcix

```cpp
QRegularExpression re("hci[0-9]"); // matches first hci1
```

this does not work either

```cpp
QRegularExpression re("hci[0-9]/gm");
```

this should return linked string

```cpp
QRegularExpressionMatch match = re.match(common_result);
```

Many AI generators of regular expression had been of no help, I do  need to learn how to build regular expression to  match "multiple entries".

Could you post/answer with the required regular expression **WITH description of each symbol**?

I did try to use AI regular expression generators - no go.

Answer (score -1):

It matches as expected, but you should use `globalMatch` instead of `match`.

The `globalMatch` method returns a `QRegularExpressionMatchIterator`, which you can use like this:

```cpp
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = re.globalMatch(common_result);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
    if (match.hasMatch()) {
        QString captured = match.captured(0);
        //.. and do some stuff with that string
    }
}
```

Note that it uses a while-loop, so it'll iterate over all matches in `common_result`.